# How to setup RestComm with VoIP Gateways?

Tags: asterisk, voip, restcomm

I have a background of asterisk where I can setup GoIP1 VoIP Gateway as one of SIP account for outgoing calls.

Asterisk setup sip.conf

```
[gsm1]
canreinvite=no
context=goip
dtmfmode=rfc2833
fromuser=gsm1
host=dynamic
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=g729
insecure=port,invite
secret=gsm1
type=friend
defaultname=gsm1
```

How can I do the same in RestComm? I 've RestComm-Core setup on my local and I don't want to go with DID Provision Providers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Restcomm binary. You need look into the file

> restcomm.conf

.

Configure the outbound proxy as shown below

```html
# Address for outbound calls
OUTBOUND_PROXY='' #Provide port if different than 5060
OUTBOUND_PROXY_USERNAME=''
OUTBOUND_PROXY_PASSWORD=''
```

Regards

TechKid

Comment: I was able to make outgoing calls by filling outbound proxy parameters above. Is there a way I can get incoming calls as well? Currently the phone calls are answered by the VoIP Gateway itself not forwarded to RestComm

Comment: For inbound calls, you will need to get your VoIP Gateway to forward calls to Restcomm. You must then create a Restcomm Voice Application to handle the inbound call. The Restcomm voice application must have a number attached that matches the DID of the "destination" SIP call coming from your VoIP Gateway.